# Why Does a Bloom Filter Need Multiple Hash Functions?

Tags: hash, hash-function, bloom-filter

I don't really understand why a bloom filter requires *multiple* hash functions (say, SHA and MD5).

Why not just make a *bigger* SHA hash, for example, and then break it up into multiple parts and treat them as separate hashes? Isn't that more efficient in terms of speed?

Comment: According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), that is done sometimes: *For a good hash function... this type of hash can be used to generate multiple "different" hash functions by slicing its output into multiple bit fields*

Comment: @Damien: I never saw that, thanks a lot. If you post it as an answer I'll +1 it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to use several different but simple hash functions. If you're going to use some cryptographic hash function like SHA or MD5 then you could just vary the input to it. Whether it's more efficient depends how complex your hash functions are.

Answer (score 1):

It's called triple/double hashing, it minimizes the chance of collisions, probability of collision occurring with 5 hash functions, is 5 times smaller than with one hash function.