# Can I use 1 instead of k hash functions to implement a bloom filter?

Tags: algorithm, hash, hash-function, bloom-filter

There is a similar question here: [Why Does a Bloom Filter Need Multiple Hash Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606642/why-does-a-bloom-filter-need-multiple-hash-functions) but it has a selected answer that is pretty vague and doesn't answer my question fully:

Instead of using k hash functions (or even just 2, as put forth in this paper: http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~kirsch/pubs/bbbf/rsa.pdf ), can I do one of the following solutions to implement a bloom filter?

1. Hash input once, partition the hash into k sections, and use the modulus of m of each of those sections as my index values.
2. Hash input once, then modulus by k prime numbers to produce k index values.

Are both of these solutions effectively implementing k unique hash functions, or is there something fundamentally wrong with each of these?  Is using k unique hash functions strictly better than the above?

Comment: The first one is effectively k independent hash functions. The second one is not; the hash functions are correlated.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Out of curiosity, how are h%p1 and h%p2 correlated, assuming that h is uniformly distributed in [0, m) and p1 and p2 are distinct primes between m^(1/3) and m^(1/2)? .... although it seems like segmenting into bit ranges is a cheaper computation...

Comment: `h%p1` and `h%p2` are not independent. Knowing `(h+1)%p1` tells you a lot about `(h+1)%p2`.

Comment: My intuition was along the same lines as rici's, thinking that although they aren't truly dependent, the results would be varied enough to be usable in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the response Raymond Chen, I'll probably go with #1 unless there is a clearly better and easier way to implement this.